# sublime linter like package for emacs (syntax error live highlighting)

Tags: emacs

In Sublime Text 2 there is a package called sublime linter, which highlights any section which  has syntax error as you type.

Is there any comparable package in emacs ?

Thanks
Murtaza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`flycheck`](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck) is a new up-and-coming replacement for `flymake` including features such as

- major-mode based checkers (instead of file name patterns),
- simple declarative checker definitions (instead of init functions)
- ready-to-use syntax checkers for a bunch of languages (instead of broken checkers using non-existing tools)
- a clean, concise and understandable implementation (instead of a almost 2k line mess of spaghetti code).

Comment: Alex, I can see that I already have the flymake mode installed, and can see the checks when editing a js file. I installed flycheck and also enabled it in my html file. I can see the FyC in the mode of the buffer. However it is not able to detect / higlight any errors? What could be the problem ?

Comment: @alexmurray: are you the author of flycheck?  If not, I don't think it's very nice to cut & paste the list of features (including the weird ',' at the end of the first item in the list but not for the 2nd and 3rd item) *flycheck* lists here without giving proper attribution: https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck

Comment: No I am not the author, but I linked to the project page at the start of the answer so its not like I'm trying to take credit for their list of features without giving attribution - the attribution is there right at the start.

Answer (score 2):

the `flymake` package is bundled with Emacs.  It has support for some languages, and there are many receipts to customize it for languages that aren't supported out of box. See [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) for more details